# How to set different comparators for each Table column ? (Eclipse plugins)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating some generic classes for future Eclipse plugins.

One of these classes is intended to add a tableviewer to a view.

I will like to create different compare methods for different columns.

```
MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator();
viewer.setComparator(comparator);
```

MyComparator extends ViewerComparator and I override compare method. I will like to define how to compare the objects based on the selected column.

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
      String columnHeaderName = .....
      if(columnHeaderName == COLUMN_NAME)
        {
       //implement sort and return ....
        }
      else if(columnHeaderName == OTHER_COLUMN){
      //implement sort and return ....
      }
     }
```

How to get the column name or the column object in compare method ?

**EDIT based on greg answer:**

Where columns are created:

```
columnObj.getColumn().addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            table.setSortDirection(direction);
            table.setSortColumn(columnObj.getColumn());             
            viewer.refresh();               
        }           
    });
```

In Comparator class:

```
private class SampleComparator extends ViewerComparator
{
    Table table;
    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        String columnName = table.getSortColumn().getText();
        if(columnName == FIRSTCOLUMN)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorting for first column");
            //Sorting implementation for this column
        }
        else if (columnName == SECONDCOLUMN)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorting for second column");
            //Sorting implementation for this column
        }

        return super.compare(viewer, e1, e2);
    }

    private void setTable(Table table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }       
}
```

Comment: What column name? The comparator compares whole rows. Do you mean you want to click on a column header and change the sort to be based on that column?

Comment: Yes, that is the behavior that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `TableColumn` in your table you need to call `TableColumn.addSelectionListener` to add a listener which is called when the column header is clicked.

The selection listener needs to remember the current column for the comparator to use.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve TableColumn object from Viewer object in compare ? Or any other method already present in ViewerComparator class ?